# как убрать текст с Toolbar(android studio)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не могу убрать надпись с Toolbar.
Все, что можно перепробовал, не получается

Я пытаюсь убрать "заводской" toolbar и вместо него посавить свой(Хочу просто шрифт поменять), но у меня никак не выходит убрать этот черный "centus", может вы подскажите что я делаю не так?

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/toolbar"
android:id="@+id/toolbar">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

> androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.centus">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Centus">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main_menu" />
    <activity android:name=".Rejestracja" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logowanie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/logowanie"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="45dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/telefon_do_logowania"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/white_80"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white_50"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/haslo_do_logowania"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/white_80"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white_50"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zaloguj"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_logowanie"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Log in"
        android:onClick="GetData"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/stworz_acc"
        android:onClick="Rejestracja_Konta"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Centus" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/cookie_regular</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

> styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cookie_regular</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

> MainActivity.java(Только его метод onCreate)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы не поменять шрифт оригинальному заголовку через `app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTextAppearance"` для тулбара?

Comment: @YuraIvanov а подскажите тогда еще, пожалуйста, как увеличить размер шрифта оригинального заголовка?

Comment: Ну так же, через тот же TextAppearance `<style name="MyToolbarTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cookie_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">45sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Мне помогло решить проблему эта строчка кода(добавьте ее в MainActivity в метод onCreate).